# C# MouseClick Event Doesn't Fire On Middle Click or Right Click

Tags: c#, right-click, mouseclick-event

This seems like it it should work but its not. I put a debug stop on the SWITCH statement. This event is only getting triggered on left click.  Nothing happens and method is not fired on middle or right click.  Any ideas?  P.S. I already tried using MouseUp and MouseDown events and same issue.

Here is my code:

```
this.textBox1.MouseClick +=
   new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.textBox1_MouseClick);

private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
            // Left click
            textBox1.Text = "left";
            break;

        case MouseButtons.Right:
            // Right click
            textBox1.Text = "right";
            break;

        case MouseButtons.Middle:
            // Middle click
            textBox1.Text = "middle";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `textBox1_MouseDown` event instead ! This works fine here; to avoid the context menue popping up you may want to disable ShortCuts. Btw: It is recommended to test a mousebutton like this: `if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left)).. etc`..

Comment: @TaW The first thing I did before I posted here was trying MouseDown and MouseUp.  I have the same issue.  Putting in a break point and the method is never fired on middle or left click.

Comment: I know you tried as you wrote it. But it still works here. Where do you put the breakpoint? The `switch` statement?

Comment: @TaW Break point is on the switch line

Comment: This is [by design](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,8c9d4490b578c0ee) for the TextBox and RichTextBox classes.  Note the test for MouseButtons.Left.  I'm not that sure why this was deemed necessary, it *might* have something to do with the built-in context menu in the native OS control.  It is fixable by deriving your own class from TextBox and overriding OnMouseUp(), now omitting the test on the button.  At which point it is likely you'll discover why it was deemed necessary :)

Comment: I know this may seem silly but have you tried : `this.textBox1.MouseDown += ...`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use the [MouseDown event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown?view=netframework-4.7.2) to trap Middle and Right mouse clicks. The Click or MouseClick events are too late in the pipeline and are referred back to default OS Context Menu behaviour for textboxes.

```
private void textBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Button)
    {
        case MouseButtons.Left:
            // Left click
            txt.Text = "left";
            break;

        case MouseButtons.Right:
            // Right click
            txt.Text = "right";
            break;

        case MouseButtons.Middle:
            // Middle click
            txt.Text = "middle";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its weird because this is exactly what I had originally tried.  I went back to the form I was working on and it is still not working.  I tried it on a new form and now it works.

Comment: @Kairan - totally understand. I often do the same myself. Only to ask a colleague to help me see the forest for the tree's. Cheers.

Comment: you solution is not firing the click event, I have some code in click need to execute
So I have to call the click method inside the mouse down event inside the right button condition

Comment: @mehdei, you didn't downvote did you? On a winform app, drop a button on the form, press F4 to bring up the properties, select the lightning ⚡ button and map the MouseDown event.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to set the attribute ShortcutsEnabled to False for that Textbox and write your code on MouseDown event.

It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the stop on event declaration? 
Also test this with middle mouse button click

```
if e.Button = 4194304 Then
    a = b //set the stop here
End if
```

If the event is not triggering even with the stop on the event declaration, something is wrong with the project, make a new one and test.

Comment: Sorry, but the middle mouse / right mouse do not hit a break point even on the event declaration (or anywhere inside).  I recreated a new Solution + project, c# winforms and same situation.